# Dynamically Adding / Removing Route in Durandal Router when application is loaded

Tags: durandal

I need help in dynamically adding/removing route in Durandal Router. What I want is after user is logged in then I would be able to add or remove specific route depending upon logged in user's type.

I tried to add/remove route from visibleRoutes/allRoutes array ... but get binding exception from knockout library...

I was hoping it would be common scenario... but still couldn't find any solution ... please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks.
Wasim

POST COMMENTS:

I tried this function to dynamically hide/show route... and similary tried to add/remove route from allRoutes[] ... but then get exception on knockout bidning

```
showHideRoute: function (url,show) {

        var routeFounded = false;
        var theRoute = null;
        $(allRoutes()).each(function (route) {

            if (url === this.url) {
                routeFounded = true;
                var rt = this;
                theRoute = rt;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (routeFounded)
        {
            if (show)
            {
                visibleRoutes.push(theRoute);
            }
            else
            {
                visibleRoutes.remove(theRoute);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code of how you were trying to do it, what errors you got, and any context for said code.

Comment: @Kal_Torak please see my updated post with code i tried

Comment: Post the error please.  Also, setting `theRoute=this;` looks highly suspicious.  I'd want to throw a breakpoint on that to double check,  but I doubt it's giving you the result you're expecting. I'd recommend looking at the router.js file to see the signature for adding a new route.

Comment: This function is written in 'router.js' and in the function "this" points to the route I want to show/hide and this is the exception i m getting "---Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: isActive is not defined; Bindings value: css: { active: isActive } ---" after that function is executed

Comment: So have you paid attention to the error and checked to make sure that an `isActive` property is defined on your viewmodel?  The KO errors are quite informative.

Comment: isActive is not in my viewmodel and it should not be. its a router.js property and this error has to do something the way I am making my route visible/notvisible.... and that was my original question to how to fix this... I hope now I would have make my problem abandonedly clear !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement.  If I were you, I would take another approach.  Rather than adding/removing routes when application loads - get the right routes to begin with per user type.

Two options, (I use both)
1) have a json service provide the proper routes per user type, this approach would be good if you need to 'protect/obscure' routes... i.e. I don't want the route referenced on any client resource.
2) A simpler solution see [Durandal.js: change navigation options per area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031226/durandal-js-change-navigation-options-per-area?answertab=active#tab-top) 
You can have a settings property identify the user type.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Durandal 2.0 no longer has the method `visibleRoutes`.  I found that the following works for me.

```
router.reset();
router.map([
        { route: 'home', moduleId: 'home/index', title: 'Welcome', nav: true },
        { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'flickr/index', title: '', nav: true }
])
.buildNavigationModel()
.mapUnknownRoutes('home/index', 'not-found');
```

This removes all previous routes, if you want to maintain current routes you could try using the `router.routes` property to rebuild the array of routes.

Answer (score 2):

In Durandal 2.0.

You can enumerate the routes to find the one you wish to show/hide.

Then change the value of: nav   property

Then run buildNavigationModel();

here is an example:

```
// see if we need to show/hide 'flickr' in the routes
for (var index in router.routes) {
    var route = router.routes[index];
    if (route.route == 'flickr') {
         if (vm.UserDetail().ShowFlickr) { // got from ajax call
            // show the route
            route.nav = true;  // or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4; to have it at a specific order
         } else if (route.nav != false) {
            route.nav = false;
         }
         router.buildNavigationModel();
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: First, `router.visibleRoutes()` is an observable array.  In other words, when you change its value, the routes automatically update.  However, the items in this array are *not* observable, so to make a change you need to replace the entire array and not just make a change to a single item in it.

So, all you have to do is find which item in this array you want to remove, and then create a *new* array *without* this item, and set `router.visibleRoutes()` to this new array.

If, for example, you find out the it is the 3rd item, then one way of doing it is:

```
router.visibleRoutes(router.visibleRoutes().splice(2, 1))
```

Note that `splice()` returns a new array where an item is removed. This new array is put into `router.visibleRoutes`.